# How to get the latest posting time of archived pages in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to get the post time of the latest post under the WordPress archive page?

I would like to add a feature to the archive page to show the latest time of posts published under that category.

Any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: This article might help https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-the-last-updated-date-of-your-posts-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to achieve this, but I can show you one possible way:

You can query your recent wordpress posts using `wp_get_recent_posts()`, limit it to 1 post.

```
$recent_post = wp_get_recent_posts(
    array(
        'numberposts' => 1, // get only one post
        'post_status' => 'publish' // only published posts
    )
);
```

After that we save the modification date of this post inside of a variable.

```
$latest_post_date = get_the_modified_date('d.m.Y', $recent_post[0]['ID']);
```

You can now output it using `echo $latest_post_date;` inside of your archive.

Sidenote:

If you want to format the date, the `wp_get_recent_posts()` function also accepts a parameter for the date format: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_modified_date/

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is fine if it works for you, but it has got 2 drawbacks:

1. It runs another query against the database, which you shouldn't have to do if you're adding something to a page that lists a bunch of posts already.
2. It doesn't have any context for the page you're on. e.g. The first archive page, or page 4. Or a category page, or tag page. (I don't see how that solution is selecting anything by category)

Here's a solution I came up with for something similar. No matter what page you're on (blog home page, year/month archive page, category archive page, tag archive page etc), it will show the date of the latest post selected for that page.

WordPress already has the function [get_the_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) but the problem is that if you run it on an archive/index page with multiple posts, it returns the date of the last post listed, not the first one. The solution is to capture the post date at the start of the post loop using the `loop_start` plugin hook.

A simple example, one you can put into a plugin or theme `functions.php` and modify:

```
$my_date_var = null;

add_action('loop_start', function () {
    global $my_date_var;
    $my_date_var = get_the_date(); /* add whatever $format parameter you want here */
});

function my_get_the_latest_date() {
    if ($my_date_var !== null)
        return $my_date_var;
    return get_the_date(); /* again, customize with $format if you want */
}
```

And then in your theme just run `my_get_the_latest_date()` wherever you want to show the date.